# RTL8727DE Driver not getting installed

Tags: drivers, 18.04, wireless

I have a HP Laptop, which used to run the rtl8727de driver smoothly. After an upgrade a few days back, my WiFi disconnects automatically. After this, it cannot search for any nearby routers.

Today, after multiple restarts, my WiFi driver seems to have lost. The WiFi adapter is showing as *unavailable*, and I am not at all able to use WiFi.

I tried `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`, and I saw that it tried to install the rtl8723de driver, but failed to do so. The logs are as follows:

```
DKMS make.log for rtlwifi-new-0.6 for kernel 5.4.0-74-generic (x86_64)
Sat Jun 12 16:00:26 IST 2021
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-74-generic'
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/btcoexist/halbtc8192e2ant.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/halmac/halmac_api.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8188ee/dm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_debug.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/halmac/halmac_88xx/halmac_api_88xx_usb.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8188ee/fw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/btcoexist/halbtc8723b1ant.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_antdiv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/halmac/halmac_88xx/halmac_api_88xx_sdio.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8188ee/hw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_soml.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/halmac/halmac_88xx/halmac_api_88xx.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/btcoexist/halbtc8723b2ant.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_smt_ant.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8188ee/led.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_interface.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/btcoexist/halbtc8821a1ant.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/halmac/halmac_88xx/halmac_api_88xx_pcie.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8188ee/phy.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_phystatus.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/halmac/halmac_88xx/halmac_func_88xx.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/btcoexist/halbtc8821a2ant.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_hwconfig.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8188ee/pwrseq.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8188ee/rf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/halmac/halmac_88xx/halmac_8822b/halmac_api_8822b_pcie.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/btcoexist/halbtc8822b1ant.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8188ee/sw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/halmac/halmac_88xx/halmac_8822b/halmac_func_8822b.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_dig.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8188ee/table.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8188ee/trx.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/halmac/halmac_88xx/halmac_8822b/halmac_api_8822b_sdio.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/btcoexist/halbtc8822b2ant.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_pathdiv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/halmac/halmac_88xx/halmac_8822b/halmac_api_8822b.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8188ee/rtl8188ee.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_rainfo.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_dynamictxpower.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/halmac/halmac_88xx/halmac_8822b/halmac_8822b_phy.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/btcoexist/halbtc8822bwifionly.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_adaptivity.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_cfotracking.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/halmac/halmac_88xx/halmac_8822b/halmac_8822b_pwr_seq.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/btcoexist/halbtc8723d1ant.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_noisemonitor.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_dfs.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/halmac/halmac_88xx/halmac_8822b/halmac_api_8822b_usb.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_adc_sampling.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_ccx.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/btcoexist/halbtc8723d2ant.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/halmac/rtl_halmac.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_psd.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_primary_cca.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_cck_pd.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/btcoexist/halbtcoutsrc.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/btcoexist/rtl_btc.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/halmac/halmac.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192c/main.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_rssi_monitor.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192c/dm_common.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192ce/dm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_auto_dbg.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/btcoexist/btcoexist.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192ce/hw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192ce/led.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_math_lib.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192cu/dm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_api.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192c/fw_common.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192ce/phy.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192cu/hw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_pow_train.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192ce/rf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/halrf/halrf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192c/phy_common.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192ce/sw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192cu/led.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192ce/table.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192ce/trx.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192cu/mac.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/halrf/halphyrf_ce.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192ce/rtl8192ce.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192cu/phy.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/halrf/halrf_powertracking_ce.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192de/dm.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192c/rtl8192c-common.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192ee/dm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/halrf/halrf_powertracking.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192cu/rf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192de/fw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192ee/fw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/halrf/halrf_kfree.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192cu/sw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192de/hw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192ee/hw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/halrf/rtl8822b/halrf_8822b.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192cu/table.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192cu/trx.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/halrf/rtl8822b/halrf_iqk_8822b.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192cu/rtl8192cu.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192se/dm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192de/led.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192ee/led.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/rtl8822b/halhwimg8822b_bb.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192de/phy.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192se/fw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192ee/phy.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192se/hw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/rtl8822b/halhwimg8822b_mac.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/rtl8822b/halhwimg8822b_rf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192de/rf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192ee/pwrseq.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192se/led.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192de/sw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/rtl8822b/phydm_hal_api8822b.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192ee/rf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192se/phy.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192de/table.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192de/trx.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192ee/sw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/rtl8822b/phydm_regconfig8822b.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192se/rf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192ee/table.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192ee/trx.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192de/rtl8192de.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723ae/dm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/rtl8822b/phydm_rtl8822b.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192se/sw.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192ee/rtl8192ee.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723be/dm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723ae/fw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/rtl8723d/halhwimg8723d_bb.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192se/table.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192se/trx.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/rtl8723d/halhwimg8723d_mac.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723ae/hal_btc.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723be/fw.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8192se/rtl8192se.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723com/main.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/rtl8723d/halhwimg8723d_rf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723be/hw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723ae/hal_bt_coexist.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723com/dm_common.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/rtl8723d/phydm_regconfig8723d.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723ae/hw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/rtl8723d/phydm_rtl8723d.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723com/fw_common.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723be/led.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/halrf/rtl8723d/halrf_8723d.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723ae/led.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723be/phy.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723ae/phy.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723com/phy_common.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/rtl_phydm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723be/pwrseq.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723ae/pwrseq.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723com/rtl8723-common.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723de/fw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723be/rf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723ae/rf.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/phydm/phydm_mod.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723de/hw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723be/sw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723de/led.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723ae/sw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723be/table.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723de/phy.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723be/trx.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723ae/table.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723ae/trx.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8821ae/dm.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723be/rtl8723be.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8822be/fw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723de/pwrseq.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723ae/rtl8723ae.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8822be/hw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8821ae/fw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723de/rf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8822be/led.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723de/sw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8822be/phy.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8822be/sw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8821ae/hw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723de/table.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8822be/trx.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723de/trx.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8821ae/led.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8822be/rtl8822be.o
  AR      /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/built-in.a
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/base.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8821ae/phy.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8821ae/pwrseq.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8723de/rtl8723de.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/cam.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8821ae/rf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8821ae/sw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/core.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/debug.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8821ae/table.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8821ae/trx.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/efuse.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/ps.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rtl8821ae/rtl8821ae.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rc.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/regd.o
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rc.c:336:11: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  .alloc = rtl_rate_alloc,
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rc.c:336:11: note: (near initialization for ‘rtl_rate_ops.alloc’)
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:269: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rc.o' failed
make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/rc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Makefile:1762: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build' failed
make: *** [/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-74-generic'
```

Connecting to an ethernet cable/ USB to mobile is how I am able to get online, but I desperately need my WiFi to be back up. Can someone please suggest the necessary steps that I can do?

Thanks.

Comment: Let's start by identifying your exact device. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks @chili555. The command does not print anything to terminal. It also exits with exit code 1.

Comment: Please try: `lspci -nn` Does your wireless appear? What is its pci.id, something like [10ec:d777] or some such.